# PHP will not write *some* of the string to mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Basically writing a string to an entry in a database.

The string is concatenated from $firsthalf and $secondhalf. $secondhalf is being pulled from a file-upload form

var_dump() repeatedly says both variables are working just fine, before and after the mysql statement. Yet it only writes the $firsthalf part of the concatenated string. I would assume at some point $secondhalf is just null, but according to var_dump(), it isn't.

Here is the code.

```
<?php
$firsthalf="0000";
$secondhalf=($_FILES['file']['name']);
var_dump($secondhalf); //success!
$TheFileName = $firsthalf.$secondhalf;
var_dump($TheFileName); //success!

/* Write to db */
$table = "category_images";
mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpassword) or die("Unable to connect to database");
@mysql_select_db($dbname) or die("Unable to select
database $dbname");
$sqlquery = "INSERT INTO $table
VALUES('$category_id','$TheFileName')";
$results = mysql_query($sqlquery);
mysql_close($link);
/* End write to database */

//Database reads the category number and the $firsthalf. 
//Magically, the $secondhalf goes disappears!

var_dump($TheFileName); //success, it's still good…wtf?

?>

<form id="Upload" action="./" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="240000"> 
    <input id="file" type="file" name="file"> 
    <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload me!"> 
</form>
```

Comment: i don't see any problem with your code :S, i tested it and got a good query, can you maybe give more details
and btw i hope that's not all your code because you do not check if a file upload occured and you just keep executing the query every time the page is loaded... not to mention that your query is not safe, and you need to put MAX_FILE_SIZE as a constant in your PHP code not your HTML: one can easily modify such a variable with Firebug or such

Comment: @Dagon im interested in knowing how could a field type trim a string's end :)

Comment: @Danny length and type, try inserting "999FISH" in to an int, or "FISH" in to varchar(1)

Comment: ah yes i forgot about length! nice catch

Comment: Add this line before the `$sqlquery =` line: `mysql_query('SET SESSION sql_mode = \'TRADITIONAL\'');` and see what happens

Comment: As an aside, you should always specify the columns when using INSERT, assuming any particular column order is just begging for trouble down the road.

Comment: The datatype is a 250 char. It's not a shortening though, I tried it also with a string concatenated to the beginning and end "stringlikethisstring" and it wrote to the db as "stringstring"

Comment: I'll move to my laptop and give these a try. If those don't work I'll just upload the file itself.

Comment: dany all those things are in the code, I just uploaded it in this form here for simplicity.

Comment: This has gotten really messy after trying to troubleshoot and move things around, but as you'll see, I've been commenting out parts of the code to find a conflict. http://ge.tt/9r81SCA?c

Comment: hmm, idk if this will be useful but try echoing `$sqlquery` perhaps the dark magic is there :S

Comment: Good suggestion, Dany. "INSERT INTO `category_images`(`category_id`, `imagename`) VALUES ('97','000greatlandingpage.png000')" (I changed the query per @mu's suggestion) So we know it's actually going that far...

Comment: I put that query in manually in phpmyadmin and it worked, so the problem must lie somewhere in here:

    @mysql_select_db($dbname) or die("Unable to select database $dbname");
    $sqlquery = "INSERT INTO `category_images`(`category_id`, `imagename`) VALUES ('$category_id','$TheFileName')";
    mysql_query('SET SESSION sql_mode = \'TRADITIONAL\'');
    $results = mysql_query($sqlquery);
    echo($sqlquery);
    mysql_close($link);

Comment: Tried changing the database field to "text" with a utf-8-general-ci encoding. no luck.

Comment: I just figured it out. I'll write the solution below.

Answer (score 0):

Does the file name contain any special characters ?

Replace your 2nd line with :

`$secondhalf=mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['file']['name']);`

This would make sure your filename is properly formatted for the query

Also as Dagon pointed out: Make sure you have the right type of field in the DB and a good length.

Comment: oh I hadn't thought of that. Let me move to my laptop and give it a try.

Comment: Here's what was wrong: the category id was the primary key for the table. Once the form loaded for the first time, it already wrote the nothingness of the form upload data to that category's row. After the user tries to upload it again, the database rejects the sql statement because it already has $firsthalf and $secondhalf (null right from the start) in that row. This can be fixed by not having that as primary key or just by making an "isset" condition. Thanks everyone. PHEW!

Comment: yup, thats what i meant when i said : 'you do not check if a file upload occured and you just keep executing the query every time the page is loaded'
im glad you figured it out by yourself tho :)